# qnap nfs mounting delays after Ubuntu Updated

Tags: 20.04, mount, nfs, nas

After last Ubuntu Update (20.04 LTS), when I mount my qnap nfs shares:

1. It delays for several minutes (prior to this, it took 1 second to mount it)
2. During that "long mounting time"... I can move the mouse but nothing respond to clicks, nor to keystrokes.
3. I put and "strace -t" but it was not evident where the delay is. All events are reported in the same second.
4. I have 2 different model Network adapters in the Ubuntu computer, and the behavior is the same mounting through any of them. So that, is not a problem specifically related to the network card.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is also happening with Manjaro and OpenSUSE tumbleweed on the latest 5.16 kernels. On these OSes, I had to drop back to an earlier kernel to get QNAP NFS shares working again. My systems can mount nfs shares exported from other, non-Qnap machines, so it looks as though there is some strange incompatibility with the Qnap kernel. I will let you know if I find out anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix: try mounting using NFS 3 (`mount -o mountvers=3` ...).
This got my client systems working again, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

That is the same solution I came up with but I just disabled NFS v4 from control panel.  I have 2 QNAP NAS units and one stopped responding to mount requests while the other was working fine.  I was able to compare setting between the 2 systems until I found the difference.

Go to [Control Panel][Network & File Services][Win/Mac/NFS/WebDav][NFS Service]
Uncheck [Enable NFS v4 Service] and leave [Enable NFS v2/v3 Service] checked
You will need to restart the NAS for this to work.